# PageReference PDF preview does not display data

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, blob

I'm trying to create a visualforce popup that displays a preview of a generated PDF (also using visualforce) with tables showing custom object data. The preview window displays the PDF with all the data just fine. But when I click on the "Save Attachment" button, what's saved is a PDF with table headers and no data.

This is for the popup window

```
<apex:page standardController="New_Purchase_Order__c" extensions="NewPDFController" showHeader="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" >
    <apex:form style="height:800px">    
        <center>   
            <apex:commandButton action="{!attachPDF}" value="Save Attachment"/> 
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/> 
        </center> 
        <br/>
        <center>
            <apex:iframe height="700px"  width="700px" src="/apex/NewPDFDoc?id={!MstrID}&name={!New_Purchase_Order__c.Name}&poid={!New_Purchase_Order__c.Id}"/>
        </center>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is the controller

```
public class NewPDFController {
    
    public String MstrId{GET;SET;}
    private final New_Purchase_Order__c a;
    
    public List<New_Purchase_Order__c> purchase_order { get; set; }
    public List<Line_Item__c> line_items { get; set; }
    public Double total_amount { get; set; }
    
    public String poid { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    
    public NewPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        
        poid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('poid');
        name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name');
        MstrId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        
        a = (New_Purchase_Order__c)standardPageController.getRecord();
        
        purchase_order = [SELECT Name, PO__c, Date_Ordered__c, Manufacturer__c, Material_Pickup_Location__c, Vendor_Address__c, Ship_Via__c, Sidemark__c,
                          Freight_Carrier__c, DesignTeam_Phone__c, Normalized_Manufacturer__c, Normalized_Ship_To__c FROM New_Purchase_Order__c
                          WHERE Name =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name')];
        
        line_items = [SELECT Name, Purchase_Order__c, Quantity__c, Rate__c, Amount__c, U_M__c FROM Line_Item__c
                      WHERE Purchase_Order__c =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('poid')
                      ORDER BY Name ASC];
        
        AggregateResult[] sumResult = [SELECT SUM(Amount__c)item_cost FROM Line_Item__c
                                       WHERE Purchase_Order__c =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('poid')];
        total_amount = (Double)sumResult[0].get('item_cost');
        
    }
    
    public PageReference attachPDF() {

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/NewPDFDoc');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',MstrID);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('name',name);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('poid',poid);
        
        Blob pdfBlob;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            pdfBlob = pageRef.getContentAsPDF();
        } else {
            pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('This is a test');
        }
        Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = a.Id, Name = 'pdf2.pdf', body = pdfBlob); //create the attachment object
        insert attach;
        return pageRef;
        
        //PageReference redirect = new ApexPages.StandardController(a).view();
        //redirect.setRedirect(true);
        //return redirect;
    }

}
```

Everything else works as intended. The only issue is the attachPDF() method does not grab/display object data. I'm also very new to Apex, some more insight as to what I could do better would be greatly appreciated.